# Preset Tags acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

Does acts_as_taggable_on have any settings to prevent the creation of new tags? I couldn't find anything on the wiki or on SO.

I only want admins to be able to create new tags. I realize I could create something to check the list, but I can't imagine I'm the first one to have this request.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the source code and found something that maybe can prevent tags from being saved. According to the `tag` method found here: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tagger.rb#L45, maybe if you put and option `:skip_save` it would work.
This is just a guess, i really didn't test it, just opened up the class and tried to read it.

Comment: From a brief search over on: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/208, I think that refers to the tagged object, not the tag itself?

Comment: I think the answer is somewhere in here:  https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tag.rb#L45-L66. Maybe this isn't a bad time to try my first fork on a project? lol

Comment: My thought exactly. Reading the code make me feel like trying something new.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be a acts_as_taggable_on setting.

In order to prevent certain roles from being able to access it, just have the specific restrictions around it in your view.

So, in your view - you might have the below snippet for creating tags.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (Separated by Commas)",:class => 'control-label' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list, :class => 'text_area' %>
  </div>
```

Just surround them, with you authorization code and they won't be rendered.

Example: if you are using [can-can gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) you write something along the lines of

```
<% if can? :update, tag_list %>
```

Comment: I did a poor job of phrasing. I want users to be able to use existing tags, but not to be able to create their own.

Comment: @JDewzy ah. okay :) 

In that case, I think you would still need some authorization, to decide when to call :skip_save or not?